# Disk size keeps shrinking

Tags: hard-drive, macos, bug

I am not a pro at Mac / OS X. But I know my way around.

I just installed OS X El Capitan. However when I first started up, my harddisk used 30GB with 'other'. With time the capacity just keeps shrinking. If I just stare at the screen, I just see the available space drop and drop. Until it hits Zero Bytes at capacity.

Does anyone know what I can do about this? I cannot seem to find anything on this on Google.

The only thing it returns on my keywords are things like how to remove temporary files, re-index size with Spotlight, Startup in safe mode. None of these things seem to work.

---

@Edit 22:02 06-04-2016

I have checked Activity Monitor and got the following results:
[image]

I have sorted on Bytes Written, that does not seem very strange.

However if I check the Graph Data Written below it gives:
[image]

As you can see the data Written is around 8.33 GB and a few minutes later already 10 GB,.. I checked; 'sudo fs_usage -f filesys' this keeps trying to get some attribute lists from mdworker? Don't know if that is normal?

---

@Edit 20:30 07-04-2016
With 'sudo fs_usage -f filesys' I see that the following processes write;

- nsurlsession
- nsurlstorage
- IMRemoteUrlC
- cfprefsd

With using Daisy Disk App I see the following:
[image]

So the private and library grows a bit, however the Core grows massively. I see that it produces a 'core dump' of around 528 mb every now and then. This tells cores is a folder for a core dump;

[OS X El-Capitan - /cores directory taking up a lot of space?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/215410/os-x-el-capitan-cores-directory-taking-up-a-lot-of-space)

What/why is this happening? (Like the post I have set the core dump limit to 0 and it seems to have stopped generating.)

---

PS: This is not a duplicate of [Over 25 gb of Space Disappeared](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/96836/over-25-gb-of-space-disappeared), I do not have time machine / Backups turned on.

Comment: What software do you have installed on the Mac? Something must be manipulating data on your Mac.

Comment: Nothing, It is just a clean OS X El Capitan. I do see com.apple.iconservices.store keep coming back in the cache folder?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, your hard drive keep creating new data until it's full and has no more capacity to create whatever this data is?

Comment: Jep,.. I cannot find what it is.

Comment: In that case opening Activity Monitor and looking at what processes are using the most CPU % should tell you where this data is coming from. Since this is a fresh install it should be easy to find the process causing this issue.

Comment: @slightly_toasted added some information, do you know where I can check where 8 GB data has been written?

Comment: Anything unusual on the CPU tab?

Comment: @slightly_toasted nothing much, accountsd, mdworker and iconservices all use around 1%. That are the highest processes.

Comment: data written / read might just be the pagefile (aka. RAM contents being put to disk to keep RAM load down). Download https://daisydiskapp.com (trial should do, no need to buy) and run an admin scan (hit the disclose arrow next to the scan button). Any files/folders look suspiciously massive?

Comment: @kevin9794 Thank you, found the source indeed. Only question, Why? :O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, these are core dumps. You can find more information on why they happen and how to prevent them [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/215410/os-x-el-capitan-cores-directory-taking-up-a-lot-of-space). In a nutshell, they are generated for debugging, but shouldn't be kept on disk by default. Either the system setting is wrong, or some buggy process is choosing to save them. Running

```
sudo launchctl limit core 0 unlimited
```

in Terminal will disable the system from saving them by default, but still allow processes to make them if they choose to, or running

```
sudo launchctl limit core 0 0
```

will disable them entirely, both in the system by default, and by disallowing processes from creating them. There should be no issue if you disable them completely.

Comment: It is for software developers and generated by crashes. Is this not strange for a fresh Mac OS X installation?

Comment: definitely is. Wouldn't surprise me if the installation process enables core dumps for all crashes, and disables them on completion. Maybe some bug or mishap prevented the installer from disabling them in this case.