# Deleting files but, disk space doesn't stay free - not due to time machine

Tags: macos, disk-space

After hitting the ceiling on my 256 GB SSD, I deleted around 20 GB to free up disk space.
Unfortunately, almost every time I start the MacBook, it issues a warning, that the startup disk is almost full. Seemingly at random, checking the free disk space actually provides the 20 GB of free disk space but after a while it falls down to a few MB (!).
I already tried disabling Time Machine's Local Snapshots:

**sudo tmutil disablelocal**

but that didn't help.

System Specs:
El Capitan - 10.11.6 on a late 2013 MacBook Pro

P.S.: this is not a duplicate of [Over 25 gb os Space Disappeared](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/96836/over-25-gb-of-space-disappeared)

Comment: Me too. 10GB deleted and only 300 MB freed up on 500GB drive.